# Generate Subject Key Identifier by hand using openssl command sequence

Tags: openssl, x.509

When creating a signed certificate I get the lines inside the
certificate that identify the keys used:

```
  X509v3 extensions:
     X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
         D8:D7:3F:99:CC:D7:20:AF:62:31:E2:EA:2C:8C:28:8C:B8:2F:0B:96
     X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
         keyid:D8:D7:3F:99:CC:D7:20:AF:62:31:E2:EA:2C:8C:28:8C:B8:2F:0B:96
```

Question: *Given the CA key and the server key, is there a openssl command sequence with which I can generate the Subject Key Identifier and the Authority Key Identifier by hand*?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can programatically derive the same [Key Identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2) values given the appropriate public keys?  Or are you asking if you can use openssl to arbitrarily alter the Subject and Authority Key Identifier fields of a certificate?

Comment: I would like to programatically (through openssl command calls) recreate the SKI and AKI from a key. Actually I found the answer for SKI here now: http://certificateerror.blogspot.se/2011/02/how-to-validate-subject-key-identifier.html. Does anyone know how it is done for AKI? The certificate is selfsigned, so the above two Identifiers should reference the same key, but they are different...

Comment: ehem,,,they the same. solved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From http://certificateerror.blogspot.se/2011/02/how-to-validate-subject-key-identifier.html.

Extract SKI from cert:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
openssl x509  -noout -in $1 -pubkey  | openssl asn1parse  -strparse 19 -noout -out - | openssl dgst -c -sha1
```

Extract SKI from key:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
openssl rsa -in $1  -pubout | openssl asn1parse -strparse 19 -noout -out - | openssl dgst -c -sha1
```

1. `openssl x509 -pubout` [extracts](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html) a public key from an x509 document.
2. `openssl asn1parse` [decodes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/asn1parse.html) an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) object and performs any chosen operations on it.
3. `-strparse 19` skips the first 19 bytes, a *magic* number. Typically the public keys is in [PKCS#1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017) format. So for an RSA public key of 2048 bits it starts with 4 bytes of `SEQUENCE`, 2 bytes of `SEQUENCE`, 11 bytes to store the OID `1.2.840.113549.1.1.1` meaning rsaEncryption, 2 bytes for a `NULL` terminator on the sequence. That is 19 bytes, which starts the `BIT STRING` data structure and continues to the end of the data.
4. `openssl dgst` produces the [digest](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/dgst.html) of the input using the chosen output format and digest algorithm

Comment: Could you click "Accept" if this worked for you? (That way it will no longer be listed in the "Unanswered" section.)

Comment: The first line does not work. The output if -pubkey is PEM encoded, so asn1parse needs to have -inform pem to work.  Unfortunately, -outform does not work for x509 to affect the pubkey. For ECDSA keys, I don't think that the asnparse step is needed.

Comment: @mcr: that's incorrect; asn1parse _defaults_ to -inform pem -- although unlike other OpenSSL functions it doesn't check the BEGIN/END lines, ignoring them and processing _any_ base64. But: -strparse 19 is correct only for an RSA key of at least 1800 bits (and less than about 524k bits, IINM, which shouldn't be an issue). DSA and ECDSA require different offsets, which vary depending on the group/curve used. Note `-strparse` for ECDSA without `-noout` will _display_ an error, because X9.62 point format is not ASN.1, but it still extracts correct data to `-out file`

Answer (score 0):

Extract from SKI from cert:

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl x509  -noout -in $1 -pubkey -outform der | openssl asn1parse -inform pem -noout -out tmp.pub.der
openssl dgst -c -sha1 tmp.pub.der
```

Please also be aware that SHA-1 is not used as often to form the SubjectKeyIdentifier.
SHA-256 is used, which is why it is better to have the certificate generator generate this.

Comment: That's wrong or at least unconventional; rfc5280 says you should hash only the 'bit string' (algorithm-specific) part, which the accepted answer selects using -strparse, NOT all of SubjectPublicKeyInfo as you do. And I've not seen anyone change away from SHA1 for SKI/AKI. Can you give some examples? Or are you maybe thinking of _cert fingerprints_? Those have (mostly) moved from MD5 to SHA1 and now SHA256.